# Skype spawns a process called VideoMonitor that's running after signing out from Skype. What is it and why is it there?

Tags: privacy, skype, processes

Skype version 5 on KitKat.

It's concerning, given the company's track record of lack of respect for privacy. I'm not suggesting it's taking pictures, but it could be some additional tracking of system use in general.